# Firefox unable to access domains defined in /etc/hosts if Network Manager is disconnected from a network

Tags: linux-mint, dns, firefox, networkmanager

For developing web sites, I define test domains in /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1 example.org
```

I can then access example.org in the browsers.

However I when the Network Manager is not connected to any network, Firefox is not able to access `example.org`, it gives an error similar to DNS failure. It cannot even load the localhost, if I try to access it by the host name of my machine - i.e. `http://rohit-box`.

I can access example.org, rohit-box, etc. in Chrome. I can also ping them successfully. Thus I have isolated the problem to Firefox.

I am using Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon, Firefox 19.

Edit - I also tried resetting Firefox from the Help menu. The issue persists.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you restart Firefox while NM is disconnected?

Comment: @peterph,Yes the problem remains even if I restart Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It appears firefox has switched to "Offline Mode", based on the Network Manager's reported status. You can disable this behaviour by setting "toolkit.networkmanager.disable" (all lowercase) to true in about:config.

More info [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Toolkit.networkmanager.disable)

Comment: The preference did not exist, so I added it. However, the problem was not fixed.

Comment: I checked the Offline item in the File menu - Firefox doesn't go into "offline mode" in this situation.

Comment: Same answer as other guy, kind of: the key is toolkit.networkmanager.disable (note the lower case here).

Answer (score -1):

add your domain to your ipv6 localhost

```
127.0.0.1 example.org

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback example.org
```

Comment: Tested using Firefox 32 on Linux Mint 17. Does not work.